# Using JSON to Retrieve MySQL info

Tags: json

I am learning JSON and have to try and get this example I found to work on my site but have trouble when I use it with retrieving 4 or more columns instead of the three in the example which works fine for me. The php file:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "***", "****", "inventory_form");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT FName, LName, Eqpmnt_Brwd, Service_Tag FROM Inventory");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"FirstName":"'  . $rs["FName"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"LastName":"'   . $rs["LName"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"Eqpmnt_Brwd":"'. $rs["Eqpmnt_Brwd"]     . '",';
    $outp .= '"ServiceTag":"'. $rs["Service_Tag"]     . '"}';
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

And the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
h1 {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #cc9900;
    color: #996600;
    font-size: 30px;
}
table, th , td  {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>SHS Inventory Form</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "inventory_table.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" + 
        arr[i].FirstName +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].LastName +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].Eqpmnt_Brwd +
        "</td><td>";
        arr[i].ServiceTag +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>"
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The response.txt contains the Service_Tag info :

```
"[{"FirstName":"George","LastName":"****r","Eqpmnt_Brwd":"Laptop","ServiceTag":"075247"},{"FirstName":"Nadine","LastName":"****n","Eqpmnt_Brwd":"Apple Video Dongle","ServiceTag":""},{"FirstName":"Nicole ","LastName":"*****o","Eqpmnt_Brwd":"Hovercam","ServiceTag":"075642"} etc...
```

But checking HTML on page with firebug I see the column is blank :

```
<div id="id01">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>George</td>
<td>O****</td>
<td>Laptop</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

I have put code thru JSON Lint and ok, a php validator ok and checked my MySQL statement ok but still after any third column I cant readout anything. I know its probably simple but I've stared at this for awhile with no answer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I had a syntax error:

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" + 
        arr[i].FirstName +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].LastName +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].Eqpmnt_Brwd +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].ServiceTag +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>"
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
```